# python celery invalid value for -A unable to load application

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I have a following project directory:

```
azima:
    __init.py
    main.py
    tasks.py
```

task.py

```
from .main import app

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

@app.task
def mul(x, y):
    return x * y

@app.task
def xsum(numbers):
    return sum(numbers)
```

main.py

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('azima', backend='redis://localhost:6379/0', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0', include=['azima.tasks'])

# Optional configuration, see the application user guide.
app.conf.update(
    result_expires=3600,
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

When I run a command to initialize celery workers, I get this error:

```
(azima_venv) brightseid@darkseid:~$ celery -A azima worker -l INFO
Usage: celery [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Error: Invalid value for '-A' / '--app': 
Unable to load celery application.
Module 'azima' has no attribute 'celery'
```

But when I rename `main.py` to `celery.py` as it was earlier there's no issue.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two approaches

1. import your `app` to `azima/__init__.py`

```py
from azima.main import app
    
celery = app  # you can omit this line
```

You can omit the last line, celery will recognize the celery app from the import. Then you call `celery -A azima worker -l INFO`

2. Call you application like `celery -A azima.main worker -l INFO`