# How do I resolve Module 'my_project' has no attribute 'celery' error with Docker Compose, Django, Celery?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, celery

I can't figure out why celery isn't being recognized.
Here is the full error I get when I run `docker compose up` (excluding everything else that works fine):

```
celeryworker                     | Usage: celery [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
celeryworker                     | Try 'celery --help' for help.
celeryworker                     |
celeryworker                     | Error: Invalid value for '-A' / '--app':
celeryworker                     | Unable to load celery application.
celeryworker                     | Module 'my_project' has no attribute 'celery'
celeryworker exited with code 2
```

I'm using:

- Docker version 20.10.23, build 7155243
- Django 4.1.7
- Python 3.11
- Celery 5.2.7

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11.0

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the Django project
COPY . /code/
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15.2
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment: 
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  cache:
    image: redis:7.0.10
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data/cache:/data
  rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:3.11.8
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5673:5673
      - 15672:15672
      - 25672:25672 #?
    volumes:
      - ./data/rabbit/data:/var/lib/rabbitmq
      - ./data/rabbit/log:/var/log/rabbitmq
  web:
    build: . 
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--", "uwsgi","--ini", "/code/config/uwsgi/uwsgi.ini"]
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETINGS_MODULE=my_project.settings.production
      - POSTGRES_BD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
      - cache
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.23.1
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/templates
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
  daphne:
    build: .
    working_dir: /code/my_project/
    command: ["../wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--", "daphne", "-u", "/code/my_project/daphne.sock", "my_project.asgi:application"]
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=my_project.settings.production
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
      - cache
  celeryworker:
    container_name: celeryworker
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    #command: python -m celery -A my_project.celery worker -l info
    #command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "rabbit:5673", "--", "celery", "-A","my_project.celery","worker","-l","info"] #"python","-m", 
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "web:8000", "--", "celery", "-A","my_project","worker","-l","info"] #"python","-m", 
    depends_on:
      - rabbit
      - web
```

The wait-for-it script is [here](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it).
I've tried it with and without that script and have the same issue, so I don't *think* that is that problem.

my_project/celery.py

```
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_project.settings.production")
app = Celery("my_project")
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

my_project/settings/production.py (excerpt)

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://rabbit:5672'
```

my_project/**init**.py

```
from my_project.celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ("celery_app",)
```

I've tried all sorts of iterations with changes to the commands in the docker-compose.yml file, changes in settings, with and without the wait-for-it script, etc., as well as various suggestions on the internet, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67108556/python-celery-invalid-value-for-a-unable-to-load-application), all with no luck.

I don't have any issue running a Celery worker when I run it on my computer without a Docker container.

Does anyone know why I am getting this error and how I can solve it?  Let me know if there is anything I left out.

## UPDATE

If I change the command line in the docker-compose file to either `my_project.my_project.celery_app` or just `my_project.my_project` it changes the error - then I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_project.settings'` Then I figured out that if I figured out that if rather than using `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_project.settings.production")` and `app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")` in my celery.py file, if I create a celeryconfig.py file and use `from . import celeryconfig` and `app.config_from_object(celeryconfig)`, the celeryworker container will start up successfully...but without any tasks registered.

This leads me to believe there is some issue with how Docker is reading my file hierarchy. Any ideas?

Comment: Just to confirm, you used `init.py` and not `__init__.py`?

Comment: No, sorry, I used `__init__.py` - the underscored were removed automatically, I guess I formatted it incorrectly in my post

Comment: Ah ok. In that case try to use `my_project.celery_app`, as you have defined it from `__all__`. Or if you really want to use `my_project.celery`, try deleting the `__all__` line in `__init__.py`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I think that might give us a hint - see my update above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing to fix this error:

1. in the docker-config.yml file in the celeryworker section:

   - added `working_dir: /code/dating_project/` right under build
   - added an `environement:` subsection under command and on the next line added `- DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=dating_project.settings.production`
2. Changed the name of celery.py to celeryy.py (and updated references to that file)

I'm not 100% sure which part fixed it or if it needed both changes but with those changes Celery started working and recognized the tasks files...but then I started having a problem with Daphne and I ended up abandoning Docker altogether.